# R: "R-ify' triple loop with conditions based on row position

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I managed to write a rather clunky piece of code that to a great extent does what I want but the problem is that it's slow and my database is too large which means basically no go. I made a reproducible dataset and I'll try to explain as well as possible what I need to do:

```
Y <-structure(list(X1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("23", "2636","15B","2637", "2638", "2639"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(16L, 16L, 18L, 8L, 10L, 16L, 17L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 8L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), .Label = c("1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998"), class = "factor"), X3 = structure(c(4L, 11L, 4L, 3L, 14L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 8L, 8L, 12L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 13L, 8L, 10L, 15L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 14L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 9L), .Label = c("ABT", "AZN", "BAX", "BAY", "BMS", "GET", "GSK", "JNJ", "LIL", "MER", "NOV", "PFI", "S.A", "SAG", "SHI"), class = "factor"), X4 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1980", "1988", "1996"), class = "factor"), X5 = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1981", "1990", "1991", "1997", "1998"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"), row.names = c(NA, 40L), class = "data.frame")    

Y<-data.frame(Y)
colnames(Y)<-c("s","y","f","pb","pbs")
Y[,"pbc"]<-NA
Y<-Y[order(Y$s, decreasing =F),]
Y$s<-as.character(Y$s)
Y$y<-as.numeric(as.character(Y$y))
Y$pb<-as.numeric(as.character(Y$pb))
Y$pbs<-as.numeric(as.character(Y$pbs))
```

ff<-c("BAY","NOV","BAX","SAG","BMS","PFI","JNJ","S.A","MER","SHI","ABT","GET","AZN","GSK","LIL")

In this dataframe s = sign, y = year, f = firm, pb = year of first sign, pbs = year of second sign if sign occurs within 3 years of first sign, and pbc refers to the new variable "sign confirmation". pb and pbs have been coded at the industry level and now I want to find out whether a firm that has the first sign (pb) also has the second sign (pbs). If this is the case, the value for pbc should take the value of pbs. ff is a list of all firms.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
for (j in 1:length(ff)){
a<-as.vector(table(Y[Y$f ==ff[j],][,"s"]))
for (k in 1:(length(levels(as.factor(Y[Y$f ==ff[j],][,"s"]))))) {
  for (i in 1:(nrow(Y[Y$f ==ff[j],])-1)) {
    Y[Y$f ==ff[j],][,"pbc"][i] <-
      if ((a[k] >  1) && 
            (Y[Y$f ==ff[j],][,"y"][i] == Y[Y$f ==ff[j],][,"pb"][i]) 
          && 
            (Y[Y$f ==ff[j],][,"y"][i+1] == Y[Y$f ==ff[j],][,"pbs"][i+1]))
      {Y[Y$f ==ff[j],][,"pbs"][i]}
    else {0} 
  }}}
```

It seems pretty complex but what it does is the following:

1. I isolate a specific firm j into a subdata.frame `Y[Y$f ==ff[j],]`
2. I check how many different values for "s" there are (via table)
3. Provided there are at least two rows for which a value of "s" is repeated `(a[k] >  1)` check if two other conditions are met. If so, add the value of "pbs"

Now this result works but contains two issues.

- Firstly, there are always some values that remain `NA`. I don't think they cause any problem but it would be great to get rid of those NAs at once (for my piece of mind)
- It's not very efficient and I don't think my simple computer can handle the entire dataset (with  > 2500 signs, > 30 years, > 35 firms)

Expected result with the current code (notice that the NA values ideally should not occur)

```
pbc = c(0,0,1981,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NA,NA,0,NA,,0,0,0,1998,0,0,1991,0,0,0,NA,0,NA,1(90,NA,1997,NA)
```

To further clarify how my suggested code ought to work, I ran a part of it that should hopefully more clearly show what I want to do in one go.

```
bayY<-Y[Y$f == "BAY",]
for (i in 1:nrow(bayY)-1){
  bayY$pbc[i+1] <- 
    if ((bayY$s[i] == bayY$s[i+1]) && (bayY$y[i] == bayY$pb[i]) && (bayY$y[i+1] == bayY$pbs[i+1])) {bayY$pbs[i+1]}
  else {0}
}
```

So here I'm testing the conditions for a single firm after isolating that firm. The result gives me all the right values. I could do this for every firm and then rbind all of them together in a new df but there must be a way of doing this more efficiently...

Comment: Your example gives me the following error: `Error in Ops.factor(Y[Y$f == ff[j], ][, "y"][i], Y[Y$f == ff[j], ][, "pb"][i]) : 
  level sets of factors are different`

Comment: General code suggestion: Every time you write an indexing expression like `Y[Y$f ==ff[j],][,"s"]`, you can just write `Y[Y$f ==ff[j],"s"]`. There is no need for two sets of brackets.

Comment: Your example also has problems (the error above) due to trying to compare factors with different levels. You either need to convert everything to character or numeric in order to the `==` comparisons you have throughout the code.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I forgot to put those "as.character()" commands as I did those yesterday.. I added them in edit. Thanks for the formatting suggestions, will look better.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a sample of the expected result? As Thomas states, your code gives an error.

The following code gives you at least the firms with two or more signs and the modified pbc value. In a next step, you can go on...

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Y)    # your data.frame

dt[, list(unique_signs = length(unique(s)),
          pbc          = max(unique(pbs))),
   by=list(f)][unique_signs>1]
```

Comment: ok, that should do it:
dt[, list(pbc = ifelse(length(unique(s)) > 1, max(unique(pbs)), 0 )),
   by=list(f)]

Comment: Hi Christian, I think this has potential but at the moment what it does is give me one value per firm. That is not what I need as I need for every sign the check whether or not the same firm faces it once or twice. your outcome gives me all firms, number of unique signs, and some year for pbc I cannot interpret. I would need this for every individual sign. My code works (on my computer) for a small sample, even up to 1,500 but above that the red icon in Rstudio just keeps on standing there, even for 4 hours if I set  j = 3 for instance...

Comment: I'm sorry, it is still not fully clear to me what you are trying to do...
For every FIRM, for every SIGN with at least two occurences, check if YEAR equals PB AND PBS minus PB is less than 4. If so, set PBC to PBS?

Comment: Ok, for every firm for which a sign appears at least twice (let's say rows i and i+1), if year[i] == pb[i] and year[i+1] == pbs[i+1] then set pbc[i] = pbs[i] (or set ideally pbc[i+1] = pbs[i+1]). So in the ordered Y dataframe, rows 27 and 29 have the same sign (2636) and the same firm BAY and meet the conditions, so ideally pbc[29] would be set to pbs[29]. For rows 3 and 5 the same ap[plies for BAX and sign 23. However, looking at row 4 and 14 for sign 23 and firm BAY, we see the first condition holds but pbs[14] is not equal to y[14] so the result should be zero...

Comment: The condition that pbs - pb < 4 need not be tested as the dataframe Y only contains values for pbs for which this is the case...

Answer (score 0):

@Christian Borck and @Thomas,

Thanks a lot for your help. I think I solved the problem with a simple trick. The solution for a single firm worked pretty well so I'm solving it first for one firm and then repeat the same thing for all the other firms, while including the `rbind` to make sure the results get stored in a separate dataframe.

```
tmp<-Y[Y$f == ff[1],]
for (i in 1:(nrow(tmp)-1)){
  tmp$pbc[i+1] <- 
    if ((tmp$s[i] == tmp$s[i+1]) && (tmp$y[i] == tmp$pb[i]) && (tmp$y[i+1] == tmp$pbs[i+1])) {tmp$pbs[i+1]}
  else {0}
}
PBC<-tmp

for (j in 2:15) {
  tmp<-Y[Y$f == ff[j],]
  for (i in 1:(nrow(tmp)-1)){
    tmp$pbc[i+1] <- 
      if ((tmp$s[i] == tmp$s[i+1]) && (tmp$y[i] == tmp$pb[i]) && (tmp$y[i+1] == tmp$pbs[i+1])) {tmp$pbs[i+1]}
    else {0}
  }
  PBC<-rbind(PBC,tmp)
}
```